# commands not working after editing bashrc file

Tags: bash, command, ubuntu-10.04

I need to install a programming software called cuda for my academic purpose.
googling how to install , i found these and i have done that.

```
cd ~/Downloads
sudo ./cudatoolkit_3.2.16_linux_32_ubuntu10.04.run

gedit ~/.bashrc
```

Add the following entries

```
export CUDA_INSTALL_PATH=/usr/local/cuda
export PATH=$CUDA_INSTALL_PATH/bin
```

save and exit. Then run on bash.

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

now any command is not working saying
The command could not be located because '/bin' is not included in the PATH environment variable.

I could not understand I was new to this.
can you please help me.

Comment: And, to get going again, you'll need to do `/usr/bin/vim ~/.bashrc` to fix the problem as devnull described.  Then start a new window with a login shell to check that things are OK.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You needed to preserve the earlier `PATH`.  Instead of saying:

```
export PATH=$CUDA_INSTALL_PATH/bin
```

say:

```
export PATH=${CUDA_INSTALL_PATH}/bin:${PATH}
```

Comment: i cannot use the gedit ~/.bashrc command, so how can i edit it

Comment: What do you mean by `i cannot use the gedit ~/.bashrc command`?  If it because the `PATH` variable is messed up, try `/usr/bin/gedit ~/.bashrc`

Answer (score 2):

You overrided your `PATH`, you shall use as follows:

```
export PATH=$PATH:$CUDA_INSTALL_PATH/bin
```